# Deploying GlobalValueSet and GlobalPicklist with ANT error

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, metadata, ant, deployment-api

I am trying to deploy **GlobalValueSet** and  **GlobalPicklist** with ANT but get the following error:

globalPicklists/GP0.globalPicklist  Global Value Set    0   0   **Not available for deploy for this API version**

api version I have in my package XML is 44

I had a look at the [API Metadata doc](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/216/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/api_meta.pdf) and it is formatted correctly

```
      <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>GlobalValueSet</name>
      </types>
        <types>
        <members>GP0</members>
        <name>GlobalPicklist</name>
      </types>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

`GlobalPicklist` was introduced  in `37.0` version and is available only in this version

> GlobalPicklist components are available in API version 37.0 only. In
>   API version 38.0 and later, GlobalPicklist is replaced by the
>   GlobalValueSet type.

you can read it from [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_globalpicklist.htm)

you should use only `GlobalValueSet` as it replaces `GlobalPicklist`

Comment: how do I deploy the picklists then? do I need to remove them completely from the package?

Comment: your values for picklists that are shared between picklist fields are stored as `Picklist Value Sets` in setup and it is `GlobalValueSet` in metadata api `package.xml`